# Javascript failing to show utf-8 characters

Tags: javascript, utf-8

So I'm trying to show utf-8 characters coming from JavaScript.

I should have it all:

header

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

include js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="x.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

File x.js is saved as UTF-8 (and also the other files)

It works with all my PHP files, just not when it comes from a simple alert in JavaScript.

```
alert("Prénom doit être rempli");
```

Instead the famous '?' characters are showed in the alert box.

Anything I've forgotten?

Comment: Maybe you can check (via the browser developer tools) what your HTTP response headers say about the content character set.

Comment: <Pedantry>`P`, `r`, etc. are just as much UTF-8 characters as `é`.</Pedantry>

Comment: Was your file saved using utf8 encoding?

Comment: How do i check this with the dev tool? I could not find it so far

Answer (score 2):

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-charset):

> The charset attribute gives the character encoding of the external script resource. The attribute must not be specified if the src attribute is not present. If the attribute is set, its value must be an ASCII case-insensitive match for one of the labels of an encoding, and **must specify the same encoding as the charset parameter of the Content-Type metadata of the external file, if any.**

*(My emphasis.)*

So you need to ensure that your *server* is sending the correct `Content-Type` header — either with no `charset`, or with `charset=utf-8`.

If your server is already sending the `charset` as part of the `Content-Type`, that's a good thing: Just remove the `charset` attribute from the `script` tag.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this header is also in the index.php file

Comment: @Nicolas.: But what is the **JavaScript** file served as? That's what you need to look at. Open the dev tools in your browser, go to the network tab, and look at the `Content-Type` response header. Does it have `charset`? If so, what `charset` does it have? It must either **not have** `charset`, or must have **exactly** the same text as the `charset` in your `script` tag (and it's better, frankly, to just ensure the server sends it right, then remove the `charset` from the script tag).

Comment: Dev tools said charset=utf-8 and my script is included as `<script src="js/link.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`. Now the JavaScript is only returning an alert message to test it.

Comment: @Nicolas.: Weird, I could have *sworn* that comment said `utf8` in one place and `utf-8` in another, but it doesn't (now). Anyway, I would remove `charset` from the `script` tag, as the server is sending it in the `Content-Type`, where it belongs.

Answer (score 2):

Here what you need to do: open your file in notepad and save it again (save as) and this time select UTF-8 from save-file-dialog-box. Your issue will be solved

Comment: check if javascript file also saved as utf plus ur webpage

Comment: Like mentionned in my question both are saved utf8, tried it mutiple times already